# Dataframe countif function issue

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
Return
0.0000
-0.0116
0.0000
0.0100
```

I have a dataframe of the format above and I am trying to count >0 and <0 with the following code

```
print ("Positive Returns:")
print((df['Return']>0.0).count())

print ("Negative Returns:")
print((df['Return']<0.0).count())
```

However both return 5119 which is my whole dataframe length

It is not counting correctly.. can anyone advise please?

Thankyou

*not really a duplicate since I am not asking for true/false value it can be >0.1 for example

Comment: `df['Return'].gt(0.0).sum()` instead.

Comment: `count` will give you the number of non-null values. `sum` only counts those elements that are True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` for count boolean `True`s which are processed like `1`s:

```
print((df['Return']>0.0).sum())
print((df['Return']<0.0).sum())
```

Comment: May I ask one question, how do I use averageif >0.0 ?

Comment: Sure, you need `print((df.loc[df['Return']>0.0, 'Return']).mean())`

Comment: great thanks for your help Jezrael

Comment: @JNg - you are welcome!